# Conditionally serialize the response attributes

Tags: nestjs, typeorm

I want to return a different response from a `Game` controller depending on whether or not a `User` owns the game or is simply invited to it. Essentially: filter out certain attributes from the response if the user is only invited to the game.

Here's a naive implementation of what I want using two different controllers:

```js
@SerializeOptions({
  groups: ['invited'],
})
@Get(':id')
async findOne(@User() user, @Param('id') id: string) {
  const retGame = await this.gamesService.findOne(id);
  const ability = this.caslAbilityFactory.createForUser(user);
  Throw401(ability.can(Action.Read, retGame));
  return retGame;
}

@SerializeOptions({
  groups: ['owner'],
})
@Get('full/:id')
async findOneFull(@User() user, @Param('id') id: string) {
  const retGame = await this.gamesService.findOne(id);
  const ability = this.caslAbilityFactory.createForUser(user);
  Throw401(ability.can(Action.FullRead, retGame));
  // the main difference is   ^^^^^^^^, using a different CASL rule for authorization
  return retGame;
}
```

I'm using a different set of CASL rules to allow a "full read" or not, the full read being only allowed for the game owner. That way I can attach a different `group` through the `SerializeOptions` decorator, which allows me to conditionally expose an entity attribute:

```js
@Column()
@Expose({ groups: ['owner'] })
inviteKey: string;
```

But it feels wrong to use different routes and methods to basically do the same thing, I'd like to pass a dynamic condition (`user.id === ownerId`) instead of a `group` to the `Expose` decorator, and I believe the best next thing would be to use an [interceptor](https://docs.nestjs.com/interceptors) to filter certain fields from the response. I'm not sure how to proceed from there, would an interceptor be the right approach?

Answer (score 0):

I have stumbled upon the same problem, where it makes sense to have one route but based on user rights give the result with some attributes filtered out from the response. Disclaimer: Since I'm fairly new to nestjs there are some gaps in my knowledge and it might be possible that it is not a proper way to achieve the intended result.

To achieve this you'd have to:

1. Use your already defined class with exposed/excluded attributes - using `class-transformer` and `groups` should add/remove attributes from the class when transforming to json object
2. Create an interceptor - this will intercept the response before it gets sent to clinet
3. Use the interceptor for desired routes

So in your case, it could look something like this:

1. `db/models/game.model.ts`

```js
import { Exclude, Expose } from 'class-transformer';
import { Entity, PrimaryGeneratedColumn, Column } from 'typeorm';

@Entity()
export class Game {
    @Exponse()
    @PrimaryGeneratedColumn()
    id: number;

    @Column()
    @Expose({ groups: ['owner'] })
    inviteKey: string;

    @Column()
    @Expose({ groups: ['owner', 'invited']})
    name: string;
}
```

2. `transform.interceptor.ts`

```js
import {
    Injectable,
    NestInterceptor,
    ExecutionContext,
    CallHandler,
} from '@nestjs/common';
import { classToPlain } from 'class-transformer';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';
import { map } from 'rxjs/operators';
import { Game } from 'db/models/game.model';

export interface Response<T> {
    data: T;
}

@Injectable()
export class TransformInterceptor<T>
    implements NestInterceptor<T, Response<T>>
{
    intercept(
        context: ExecutionContext,
        next: CallHandler,
    ): Observable<Response<T>> {
        // This is how you can get access to requesting user (asuming it is in the request)
        const request = context.switchToHttp().getRequest();
        const user = request.user;
        /* get your group based on the CASL rules. */
        const group = 'invited';

        // Transform the data (filter out private fields)
        return next.handle().pipe(map((data) => {
            if (data instanceof Game) {
                return classToPlain(game, { groups: [group] });
            }

            // in case there is Game[]
            if (
                Array.isArray(data)
                && data[0] instanceof Game
            ) {
                return data.map(game => classToPlain(game, { groups: [group] }));
            }

            // in case response is something else, don't touch it
            return data;
        }));
    }
}
```

3. `games.controller.ts`

```js
// Use the interceptor here - you no longer need `/games/full/:id` route
@UseInterceptors(TransformInterceptor)
@Get(':id')
async findOne(@User() user, @Param('id') id: string) {
    // Return the Game instance here, interceptor will take care of transforming it
    return this.gamesService.findOne(id);
}
```

As a result to your `GET /games/:id` as user with `Action.Read` access the output should be

```json
{
    "id": 1,
    "name": "Best game in the business"
}
```

As a result to your `GET /games/:id` as user with `Action.FullRead` access the output should be

```json
{
    "id": 1,
    "inviteKey": "super-secret-invite-key",
    "name": "Best game in the business"
}
```

Hopefully this helps.